# How to get all text between two tags including php tags

Tags: php, string, get, find

I have this string:

```
$str = 'This is the content total <div class="brown">This content brown</div> and this another content <div class="red">This is content brown</div> and this finish.';
```

I want find in $str all between `'<div class="brown">'` and `</div>`, but I want too the tags.

I want obtain this in one var `$find = '<div class="brown">This content brown</div>';`

And then delete the obtained part of the initial text

```
$str = 'This is the content total and this another content <div class="red">This is content brown</div> and this finish.';
```

I have tried this function:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }
```

But this function not obtain tags, I want tags too.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a DOM parser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Hello, I just saw what you have offered, in principle I don't want to get from the html, since the variable comes from a field of a database table, I want to get the content of that variable, thanks.

Comment: What you've shown is still html, no matter where it came from, you can still parse it with a suitable tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've rewritten your `get_string_betwen` method. And included the code I used to test it. Does this meet your requirements? And to get the other string, simply use `str_replace` as shown bellow.

```php
$str = 'This is the content total <div class="brown">This content brown</div> and this another content <div class="red">This is content brown</div> and this finish.';

$result = get_string_between($str, "<div", "</div>");
echo "<pre>" . htmlentities($result) . "</pre>";

$cleanedString = str_replace($result, "", $str);
echo "<pre>" . htmlentities($cleanedString) . "</pre>";

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
    $offset = strpos($string, $start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end) - $offset + strlen($end);
    return substr($string, $offset, $len);
}
```